# How can I boot into Arch Linux using initramfs, in Ubuntu's grub?

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2

I have two hard drives, with two corresponding Grubs. One is from Arch Linux, and the other is from Ubuntu. Using Arch's grub, I can boot into either distribution. However, using Ubuntu's grub, I can see both Arch and Ubuntu, but cannot boot into Arch. I get the error:

```
Kernel offset
End kernel panic. Not syncing: VFS.
Unable to mount root fs on unknown-block.
```

I compared `grub.cfg` for both distributions. In Ubuntu's grub, I can see an entry for Arch, with the following line.

```
initrd /boot/intel-ucode.img
```

I changed it to follow Arch's `grub.cfg`:

```
initrd /boot/intel-ucode.img /boot/initramfs-linux.img
```

Now I can boot into Arch from Ubuntu's grub. It appears that Ubuntu is not appending this required option by default. How can I make Ubuntu automatically create the correct entry?

#### Edit

I'm updating Arch's grub with `grub-mkconfig -o /boot/grub/grub.cfg`. In Ubuntu, I've tried both `update-grub` and the raw command above (which it is aliased to).

#### Edit 2

The uncommented lines of `/etc/default/grub`

```
GRUB_DEFAULT="saved"
GRUB_SAVEDEFAULT="true"
GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT_QUIET="true"
GRUB_TIMEOUT="3"
GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR="`lsb_release -i -s 2> /dev/null || echo Debian`"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT=""
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""
```

Comment: Did you tried with "update-grub" and "grub-mkconfig" commands?

Comment: @MasterPiece Yes, sorry, I've clarified in an edit.

Comment: update-grub2?  It's a bit different.  I believe the latest ubuntu uses that.  Can you also drop in your grub.cfg.  Odds are you just need an entry for ArchLinux in your config.  I'm surprised it wasn't auto detected.

Comment: `update-grub2` is aliased to `update-grub`. I actually do see an Arch entry, and it is detected; it just has the wrong settings. I'll clarify in an edit.

Comment: check /etc/default/grub for your settings as well.  As long as you update the settings and run update-grub you should be okay.  Though are you sure it's using the Ubuntu grub.  If you have 2 different grubs, you can only have one active at a time.  Which one is installed on the MBR.. that's the one that's active.  You might need to re-install it on the MBR (ie.  /dev/sda  instead of /dev/sda1 )

Comment: @csgeek As per the question, I have two hard drives. I am certain that the problem is with the Ubuntu grub only because (a) I installed Ubuntu grub on sda, and (b) Ubuntu grub has Ubuntu branding in the header (Arch has none). `/etc/default/grub` is not substantially different to Arch's grub. In any case, it hasn't changed since Ubuntu's grub last worked. I've edited the contents in anyway.

Comment: There's a bug report on https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/os-prober/+bug/1635781

Answer (score 2):

Actually, there are two files that need to be modified to solve this problem. I've tested this on my Lubuntu 16.04.1 and Manjaro Linux.

In Ubuntu:

1) File **/usr/lib/linux-boot-probes/mounted/40grub2**
there is a function parse_grub_menu that doesn't handle all initrd parameters. You need to modify '**case "$1" in ... initrd)**':

a) remove assignment

```
initrd="$(echo "$2" ...)"
```

b) add two lines in place of the removed one:

```
shift 1
initrd="$(echo "$@" | sed 's/(.*)//')"
```

2) File **/etc/grub.d/30_os-prober**
within a for loop fix the assignment of LINITRD:

```
for LINUX in ${LINUXPROBED}; do
...
    LINITRD="`echo ${LINUX} | cut -d ':' -f 5 | tr '^' ' '`"
```

The first fix takes all available initrd info for Manjaro into account. The second fix cleans up the generated initrd line by changing some '^' characters to spaces.

Comment: There's a bug report on https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/os-prober/+bug/1635781

Answer (score 2):

I'm running Manjaro and Arch but, ironically, Manjaro will make a similar mistake as Ubuntu. So perhaps the following patch in 30_os_prober can still help someone.

After:

```
LINITRD="`echo ${LINUX} | cut -d ':' -f 5 | tr '^' ' '`"
```

Add:

```
if [ "${OS}" = "Arch Linux" ] ; then
  LINITRD="/boot/intel-ucode.img ${LINITRD}"
fi
```

Comment: Hi, Naiky. I'm no longer using Ubuntu, nor dual booting, so I can't test this any more. Thank you for posting though, and welcome to SE. +1 for your effort joining and posting!

Comment: I think this is wrong, you should be adding  /boot/initramfs-linux.img and not /boot/intel-ucode.img.

Comment: I've reported this to Ubuntu Launchpad for the os-prober package since I don't know of any active upstream.

Answer (score 0):

It worked after editing the `grub.cfg` file and running:

```
sudo update-grub
sudo grub.mkconfig
```