# Ubuntu grub os probe creating bad entry for Arch

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, uefi

I recently did a new build, and wanted Arch on it - I have heard good things about it. Naturally, I also wanted a few others on there to make sure I had something I 'knew' how to run. Neither Ubuntu 18.04.2 nor Ubuntu 19.04 was capable of creating a grub entry that could boot Arch, even though they both found it.

Apparently they got fooled by the existence of a microcode update in EFI boot, and attempted to initrd ONLY the microcode, not initramfs-linux.img as exists in the Arch boot setup. I have tried editing the grub.cfg (yes, I know that is not persistent) just to see if that was the (entire) problem, and it appears to be so. The question then, is how do I fix it in a persistent manner?

Thoughts that occur are an attempt to modify the 30_ entry in /etc/default so it works better - skipping 30_ and doing a 40_custom for the other distros - using another boot loader? Is there an even better way - that doesn't require modifying each additional distro after installation, perhaps? I would hate to have to add "/initramfs-linux.img" to the Arch entries in grub.cfg over and over...

freebird54

Comment: You might want to see:  https://askubuntu.com/questions/628206/how-can-i-boot-into-arch-linux-using-initramfs-in-ubuntus-grub

Comment: Some examples here, plus discussion in pages before & after this post: https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2076205&p=13787614#post13787614

Comment: Both approaches apparently work! Just a matter of 'style', I guess. Going with @oldfred because I have a lot of custom to do anyway :)

Comment: Both of these are only suggestions that you can take.  You ultimately can write your own answer here that you have done with details so that you can help others that are experiencing the same or similar things.